# In which layer should the AppDBContext be put in?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I am doing my first webAPI with .net and I am trying to implement the Clean Architecture in my project. But I do not know where should I put my AppDBContext. Here is my code.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace ReactNoteAPI.Data
{
    public class AppDBContext : DbContext
    {

        public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Notes;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `DbContext` is literally the model. Where you might implement your own unit of work and repositories, the `DbContext` is a unit of work and each `DbSet` is a repository.

Comment: so it will be okay if I put it on my Domain Layer?

Comment: Your question lacks any detail which the answer would depend on.

Answer (score -1):

DbContext fits into the Data Access Layer; it is a term entirely specific to the Microsoft Entity Framework
The WebAPI abstraction, as a design pattern with service architecture is a .net platform solution technology named Microsoft WebAPI
It works right out of the box in a mature solution stack
A DbContext class works with the idea of domain object entity, separate from data persistence; so basically all the same to the developer when plugged into Sql Server, MongoDb etc
The command lines below are related to .net project layer building

```
            echo@ off
            dotnet new mvc -o fqSSDb
            cd fqSSDb
            cls
            echo dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
            dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite
            REM echo "add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer"
            REM dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
            cls
            echo "dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design"
            dotnet add package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design
            cls
            echo "dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design"
            dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design
            cls
            echo "dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools"
            dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
            cls
            echo "dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator"
            dotnet tool install --global dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator
            cls

            echo "Finally..."

            dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=fqSSDb;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o fqSSDb -c "fqSSDbContext" -d --context-namespace fqSSDb --context-dir fqSSDb


            REM https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/tools/dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator?view=aspnetcore-6.0
            REM Uninstall aspnet-codegenerator
            REM It may be necessary to uninstall the aspnet-codegenerator to resolve problems. For example, if you installed a preview version of aspnet-codegenerator, uninstall it before installing the released version.
            REM  The following commands uninstall the dotnet-aspnet-codegenerator tool and installs the latest stable version:

            REM Now easily you can generate CRUD code by applying the following command :
            dotnet aspnet-codegenerator controller -name fqRequestController -m fqRequest -dc fqRequestDbContext --relativeFolderPath Controllers --useDefaultLayout --referenceScriptLibraries 

            REM note: but before run that command make sure you have made the necessary changes at your 
            REM - appsettings.json
            REM       - "ConnectionStrings": {"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=fqSSDb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"}
            REM - startup.cs file
            REM     var fqssdbConnectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("fqSSDbConnection");
            REM     builder.Services.AddDbContext<FqSSDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(fqssdbConnectionString));
```

Comment: this is a batch file with helpful commands for the data layer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).